# Jodit react editor loses focus on onchange method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, plugins, jodit

In react-jodit plugin, when we use onchange event, it loses focus from input after typing one character. I am attatching image of code[image] :

How to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 4):

Just initialize the config inside `useMemo`:

```
import React, {useState, useRef, useMemo} from 'react';
import JoditEditor from "jodit-react";

const Example = ({placeholder}) => {
    const editor = useRef(null)
    const [content, setContent] = useState('')
    
const config = useMemo(
    () => ({
        readonly: false, 
    }),
    []
);
    return (
            <JoditEditor
                ref={editor}
                value={content}
                config={config}
                onChange={newContent => {setContent(newContent)}}
            />
        );
}
```

Comment: At times the cursor returns to the beginning of the text in the editor by itself.